# Windows client asks for password, Linux does not

Tags: windows, samba, file-sharing

I am about at the pulling-out-my-hair stage.
I am rebuilding my home NAS box and is struggling to set up SAMBA.

I want to have anonymous guest-based authentication-free shares that is accessible to all the machines on my network which include devices that run Windows, Linux and Android.

I forgot to make a backup of my old samba config but this is what I have after days of research:

```
[global]
    workgroup = WORKGROUP
    map to guest = bad user
    guest account = nobody

[share]
        path = /var/samba_lz
        browsable = yes
        guest ok = yes
        read only = no
```

The problem is that the share works flawlessly on my Linux and Android devices, but NOT on Windows! Windows keeps popping up the auth dialog and no combinations of usernames+passwords that I can think of works and it does not allow me to just leave it blank.

The server is Ubuntu 14.04 and the version of Windows that I am having problems is 7. The directory `samba_lz` is chmodded to 777 and belongs to the main user account of the machine.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: in windows try from dos net use x: \\servername\sharename "" /user:""

Comment: OK your suggestion worked... It asked for a username and password and I provided the UNIX credentials used on the server. When I retried the share it worked... Can you explain what the hell happened? I assume that even though it works it is not the guest account that is providing me with access?

Comment: When I look at the owners of test files created in the share I can see that all the files created by my Linux machines belong to `nobody` and `nogroup` as designed. The test files created through windows belongs however to my main UNIX user, who's credentials I provided during the command you suggested. I then added a `guest only = yes` directive to the `share` stanza and even though the share still works in windows, all files I create now belongs to `nobody` and `nogroup` as it's supposed to. I am thoroughly confuzed...

Answer (score 2):

Okay so the comment from user c4f4t0r sent me down a rabbit hole and I think I figured out what was the problem.

Since the NAS box has the same name and the share is the same name, Windows had some stored credentials that it used to attempt connect to the share. Since the credentials changed on the rebuilt NAS box it failed when Windows tried to connect. For some reason the old credentials bounced off the server and I was not able to get in.

Deleting any instance of these credentials seems to have fixed the problem:

1. Running `net use` in cmd will display a list of remembered credentials used when accessing network assets. I had a stored credential for this share in this list.
2. Running `wmic netuse` will then display the actual username used when connecting to the share.
3. And finally running `net use * \d` removed all the stored credentials. If there are credentials that are not to be removed then something like `net use \\ProblemServer\ProblemShare /delete` should then delete only the credentials for that share.
4. At this stage the share still works but only for a while. After about 5 minutes I get the damned credentials box again. Only now I can type in literally anything and it will work!
5. So to get around this problem I ran `net use \\server\share "" /user:""` and then the share magically worked. As I understand it I told Windows now to always send a blank username and password whenever I try to access the share.

After this I was able to open the share without Windows asking for any form of credentials any more.

Anyone with a better solution or an explanation why this might be happening is welcome to chime in!